# Central axis motor or wheel motor for conversion to electric bike?

Tags: wheels, electric-bike, battery

I'm planning to convert my "mechanical" bike into an E-bike for riding long distances to work, and I would like to buy only the motor kit since I already have the bike. I can see that I have two options for motor kits: **central axis motor** and **wheel motor** (see pictures)

[image] vs [image]

Intuitively, I think the wheel motor is more practical and better since I can keep the gears from the original bike. It's also easier to install/remove. The central axis motor involves more mechanical work and the front gears would vanish, but it is a bit more hidden, so to say.

I can find the same engine power for both options, but I can't figure out which one should I get and I would like to hear your opinion about this. Which one should I go for and why? What are the drawbacks of one and the advantages of the other?

Thank you!